# how to override axis2 service response return parameter name

Tags: apache-axis, axis

I have upgraded my web services from apache axis1 to axis2, but I wanted to send the same response as it was earlier.

My axis1 response looks like below

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <testServiceResponse xmlns="http://webservices.com.test.com">
     <testServiceReturn>SUCCESS</testServiceReturn>
    </testServiceResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and My axis2 response is

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns:testServiceResponse xmlns:ns="http://webservices.com.test.com">
      <ns:return>SUCCESS</ns:return>
     </ns:testServiceResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I still wanted to send the response tag as 'testServiceReturn' instaed of 'return'.

Thanks in advance.